# Wordpress, custom fields value not showing, instead post id is shown using ACF or Standard custom fields via screen options

Tags: wordpress, iframe, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I have a migrated wordpress site, that has a custom field exclusive to a theme. The new wordpress site will not have this same theme but I am hoping to use the same custom field. Since I am using the same database, the custom field values are still present, and still attached to the posts.

I have downloaded ACF and have created a field with the same name, and this appeared to work, however it shows the post id inside the value instead of the meta_value.

The custom field values are iframes (vimeo videos), so I would need to essentially pull the values from meta_value and embed them on the respective posts, i've managed to echo/print the iframe onto the page but it just showed as the iframe code (), so hoping someone can guide me.

Thank you in advance, and sorry if this has been asked before I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: Means you want theme custom fields to work with ACF?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I explained it clearly.  I don't really have a preference if it is a WordPress custom field, or a ACF field. I simply need it to work. Right now it shows the Post ID rather than the meta_value, that's the issue I am having. 

So post ID: 1406 has the meta_value of an iframe

When I add the field to wordpress custom fields or ACF the value field displays the Post ID, not Meta_value